# How to make a line following robot using arduino and a funduino '3 lines robot tracker'?

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

I have already made an obstacles avoider robot , but right now I'm trying to make a line follower using a shield , arduino UNO board, a '3 lines robot tracker',and as you may know it has 5 pins (VCC, GND , R , L , C) so I'm a bit confused about what I should connect to R , L , C . It is evident that VCC receives 5V and Gnd will have to be connected to Gnd right ? So can you help me with the pins (R, L ,C) ? Could you also provide me with the programming code ? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's supposed to be R as **R**ight, L as **L**eft and C as **C**enter signals. These outputs are signaling under which sensor is the line.